# How to setup the Sales Reps Start Sending Email Through Salesforce

Tags: apex-email-service, sales-process

I am following Trailhead tutorials **(Sales Productivity)** from the link : https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sales_admin_maximize_productivity/units/sales_admin_maximize_productivity_unit_2.

In this I have Turn on one of the email services your company uses.
[image]

**The problem which I see is that, I dont know how can I get the following UI ? I need help in that**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prompt will only appear to your users when to attempt to create a New Email from a record **WITHIN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE**. You will need to grant a user permission called *Send Email through External Email Services* to any Profile who wishes to be able to use the external services.

1. Setup > Users > Profiles
2. Click the Profile label you wish to grant this user permission
3. Scroll down to Administrative Permissions
4. Check "Send Email through External Email Service"

All users with the above-changed profile will now get the prompt upon creation of Email.[image]

**To Test:**
In an Opportunity record, show the Activity list and choose to Send Email.

[image]

Comment: Just asking from Curiosity perspective, is this option not available in classic ?

Comment: @user4567570, This is a feature introduced in Summer '16 and is only available in Lightning. [Summer '16 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_productivity_email_integration.htm). Please mark as accepted answer for others in the community.